# error while filtering data as per columns in django template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using Django template to display a table and I wish to filter data based on columns 
In order to do so, I have taken two var q and r in my javascript

```
function go(){
    // alert("hellonikhar");
    var q = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var r=document.getElementById("columnName").value;

    window.open("/?q="+q+"&r="+r,"_self");    
}
```

In my home.html I have made a text-field and a drop-down menu

```
<input type="text" class="text_field" id="search" placeholder="Search 
for..." required>
<select name="columns" id="columnName">
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> Customer Name</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> Status</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> Product</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> OS Type</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> Server Type</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> L3</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> Version</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> PM</option>
    <option value="{{column.name}}"> CDM</option>
</select>

<input type="button" class="button" onclick="go()" value="go" id="submit">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="exp()" value="export" id="exp">
```

I have defined a function in my views.py to check the value of r from the drop-down and q when the go button is clicked but the data is not filtered based on those columns

```
def user_profile(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q','')
    custom = Customer.objects.all()
    r= request.GET.get('r','')

    if q and r=="Status":
        custom1=custom.filter(name__contains=q)
```

currently, I'm just testing when the value in the drop-down is status

Comment: without taking value from the dropdown my function is working fine only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed **r** parameter.

```
window.open("/?q="+q+"&r="+r,"_self");
```